# Outlook Doesn't Display my default calendar view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, default-settings

Need help with my Outlook default calendar view. Outlook does not display my calendar by defaut.

It displays my historical list of meetings but not my daily/weekly calendar. Please have a look at it and suggest how I restore my default calendar view.

[image: http://imgur.com/c54X3iI]

Answer (score 5):

This morning, my view showed up like this even though I was already set to calendar view. I had to reset mine by moving to list view and then back to calendar view to get it to work right.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### It displays my historical list of meetings but not my daily/weekly calendar.

To reset the view to the monthly view:

- menu "View" > "Arrange By" > "Current View" > "Day/Week/Month"

To set the "month" view to be the default:

- menu "View" > "Change View" > "Apply Current View to Other Calendar Folders" > "Select Your Calendar" > Click "Ok"

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution in outlook "Version 2109 (build 14326.20962 Click-to-Run)" was:

View > Change View > Calendar

Then restart outlook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this occur with Outlook 365 Version 1910.

I was able to get the Calendar to open by default in the Month view by running:

```
outlook /cleanviews
```

Note when you open Outlook using the /cleanviews switch you will wipe out all custom views and return all default views to "factory default".

Comment: **This would not be recommended...** due to the obvious - _**all custom views will be removed**_.  Why would such an issue necessitate removing all custom views, when the solution is to simply change the currently selected view from the Ribbon View tab _(as correctly answered by @DavidPostill)_?